# Explorer.exe connecting to IP addresses

Tags: virus, comodo-firewall

I run Comodo on Windows 7, and within the last couple of days, I notive that explorer.exe is trying to connect to port 80 on the following IP addresses:

```
23.199.200.154
5.196.196.149
185.48.59.20
```

How can I track down what process is calling explorer to do this?  Or is there another way to try to figure out what is going on?

Comment: You could also use TCPView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to see what's trying to connect to what from your machine .. Do you happen to have any extensions or plugins installed for Explorer (those might be the culprit if it's direct from explorer.exe) .. the IP 23.199.200.154 resolves to a23-199-200-154.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com which Akamai is a CDN (content distribution network).

Comment: This is explorer.exe, not IE... which is what is strange...

Comment: Akamai may be delivering content for Microsoft. See http://pressf1.pcworld.co.nz/archive/index.php/t-33444.html

Comment: So, odd thing is that I run Comodo, rarely use IE, have AVG installed, and also ran a scan with Windows Defender.  Nothing.  Then I stumbled upon an article that said to check for c:\programdata\{9a88e103-a20a-4ea5-8636-c73b709a5bf8}\opengl32.dll  TO my surprise, it was there, from the day before.  Nothing caught anything wrong with it, but then I installed Norton Power Eraser which found it, deleted it, and solved it.  I wonder how I can tell how this got there, and how to ensure that nothing else is wrong.  I did have Comodo blocking all of the outgoing connections, so nothing ever made it